# The DELETE statement conflict REFERENCE constraint in db, EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

First question: I encountered problem when occurred while attempting to update the database:

> DELETE statement conflict REFERENCE constraint "FK_Products_ProductTypes_ProductTypeId". A conflict occurred in the database "GdmStore", table "dbo.Products", column 'ProductTypeId'.

Second question: is my object model good and the relationship between entities?  I have to make a database where I have a  many different "products"  and each "product" has its own set of "parameters".

My DataContext:

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> opts) : base(opts) { }

public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProductParameter> ProductParameters { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
           .HasOne(c => c.ProductType)
           .WithMany(e => e.Products)
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductTypeId)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Parameter>()
           .HasOne(Pr => Pr.ProductType)
           .WithMany(Pt => Pt.Parameters)
           .HasForeignKey(Pr => Pr.ProductTypeId)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductParameter>()
            .HasOne<Product>(bc => bc.Product)
            .WithMany(b => b.ProductParameters)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductParameter>()
            .HasOne<Parameter>(bc => bc.Parameter)
            .WithMany(c => c.ProductParameters)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

These are my model classes:

```
public class Product //: BaseObject
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public double PrimeCost { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductTypeId")]
    public int  ProductTypeId {  get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    public int ProductParameterId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductParameter> ProductParameters { get; set; } = new List<ProductParameter>();
}

public class ProductType 
{   
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Parameter> Parameter { get; set; } = new List<Parameter>();
    public ICollection<Product> Product { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}

public class Parameter
{
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductTypeId")]
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductParameter> ProductParameters { get; set; } = new List<ProductParameter>();
}

public class ProductParameter 
{
    public int ProductParameterId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }

    public Parameter Parameter { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One clear question at a time.

Comment: Add the operation you are trying to execute when you get the exception. This looks like you're trying to delete a product type while a product is still referencing it.  On a general first observation I would suggest removing any bi-directional references you do not need. For instance, does a ProductType really need a list of Products? (You can always query this from the Product side with a `context.Products.Where(x => x.ProductType.ProductTypeId == productTypeId)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, it looks like you're trying to delete a row that another row depends on.

For example, look at the following tables:

```
--------------------------------------
         PRODUCT_TYPE
--------------------------------------
(PK)PRODUCT_TYPE_ID  |  TYPE
--------------------------------------
1000                 | Gimmick
1001                 | Life Changing



--------------------------------------------------------
                     PRODUCT
--------------------------------------------------------
(PK)PRODUCT_ID | (FK)PRD_TYPE_ID  | Name
--------------------------------------------------------
6521           | 1000             | Electric Pizza Cutter
6522           | 1001             | Bidet
```

If I tried to run `DELETE FROM PRODUCT_TYPE WHERE PRODUCT_TYPE_ID = 1000` it would fail.  Why?  Well if I delete that product type, then my Electric Pizza Cutter product would have a mystery product type (there *is* no 1000 anymore).  It's orphaned.  Databases aren't like Daddy Warbucks -- they hate orphans.

If you really have to delete something, you need to disassemble it from the bottom of the  chain all the way to the top.  But you'll find that very rarely should anything *ever* be deleted in a database.  Instead of deleting, you should flag it as inactive. My preferred route is using an end date.

```
--------------------------------------------------
         PRODUCT_TYPE
--------------------------------------------------
(PK)PRODUCT_TYPE_ID  |  TYPE          |  END_DATE
--------------------------------------------------
       1000          | Gimmick        | 3-25-2019
       1001          | Life Changing  | null
```

Just like that, my product type is no longer being used, but older things in the DB can still reference them if needed.